# The best way to represent simultaneity in storytelling

Tags: time, timeline

What is the best way to represent many events at the same time in UI in order to perform a storytelling? Do you have some source of inspiration?
 
Some examples of application of this case:
 
1) I want to represent different events on a map and the progression (with their start, development and end) of these events. 
 
2) I want to tell different stories, communicating that they are happening in the same time.

Answer (score 2):

As you've asked for a source of inspiration, I would like to share the brilliance of [Minard's map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Joseph_Minard#/media/File:Minard.png) with you. *Tufte regarded it as the  best statistical graphic ever drawn.*

It has elements of storytelling, data, distance, latitude, temperature, direction of travel and location - all in one map! **Essentially, it integrates four types of information design - Space, Time, Numbers and Events.**

[image]

This might not be a direct solution for your problem, but it gives a good direction on how to combine several elements together in one map.

As quoted in one of the books on information design:

> Minard’s graphic has become something of a self-perpetuating industry
>   and continues to fascinate designers, information architects,
>   information scientists, statisticians, teachers, and students; it is
>   truly the 800-pound gorilla in the information design room.

Answer (score 0):

There are several alternatives, many of which can be used at the same time.

1: If space allows have them at the same horizontal space on the story board.
There is a timeline going left to right somewhere and you have one story flowing on 'line 1', one flowing on 'line 2', etc...

2: Where you have only two different plot lines then have the timeline in the middle and one plotline above, one below. This really lets the reader easily see the plotlines in isolation or as part of a whole.

3: Use colour to link the same 'plot lines' together. It is best combined with 1 but if space is limited and some plotlines can vanish for a few months only to reappeat this still helps to keep them connected.

4: Physically connect them. If you have one event on Monday and Tuesday but then it goes quiet until Saturday then have a very thin line of the same colour running between Tuesday and Friday to link them together.

5: Use common images to tie the stories together. e.g. if one plot line is about your main character dealing with Bob then have a picture of Bob in the events dealing with him. If another is dealing with your character doing something on her iPhone then have an iPhone picture in those events.